# AWS S3: Uploading a file to S3 bucket from XAMPP PHP application throws error

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket from my XAMPP environment. Following is the PHP code

```
    require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';
    include_once("/external/aws/aws.phar");
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;


    $awsAccessKey = "*****";
    $awsSecretKey = "*****";
    $region = "Ireland";

    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key'    => $awsAccessKey,
        'secret' => $awsSecretKey,
        'region' => $region,
        'version' => '2006-03-01'
    ));

    $bucket = "mybucketset";
    echo "Using bucket named ".$bucket."\n";


    $key = 'hello_world.txt';
    echo "Creating a new object with key {$key}\n";
    $result = $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Body'   => "Hello World!"
    ));

    echo "Downloading that same object:\n";
    $result = $client->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key
    ));
    echo "\n---BEGIN---\n";
    echo $result['Body'];
    echo "\n---END---\n\n";
```

I get the following error

```
  Using bucket named mybucketset Creating a new object with key hello_world.txt 
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. 
  (cURL error 7: Failed to connect to ***.***.***.***: Host is down (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))' in phar:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ton/external/aws/aws.phar/Aws/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php:79 Stack trace: #0 phar:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ton/external/aws/aws.phar/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(199): 
  Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider->Aws\Credentials\{closure}(Array) #1 phar:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ton/external/aws/aws.phar/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(152): 
  GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(2, Array, Array) #2 phar:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ton/external/aws/aws.phar/GuzzleHttp/Promise/TaskQueue.php(60): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() #3 phar:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ton/external/aws/aws.phar/GuzzleHttp/ in phar:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ton/external/aws/aws.phar/Aws/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php on line 79
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

First thing i checked is the validity of key and secret and they are good

Comment: Ther eis some problem in AWS. It seems they can't reach their host server. Do you restrict internet access for your server?

Comment: Not at all. No restriction made in any means